# Giving Feedback on the G Play Store Internal 20 Testing Application

Tags: google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I am unable to find the Feedback option of the Google Play Store Under Internal Testing application. Let me know how to provide Feedback to the Internal Testing application. I am totally stuck in that a little help will be appreciated. I have tried Play store documentation but I didn't find any way to give review or feedback and there is no such a video or tutorial on the YouTube which showed how to provide feedback or review on the Under Internal Testing application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Internal Testing Tab, there is a box to provide an email address or URL for users to provide feedback, just fill this in with your URL or email.

[image]

Comment: that was helpful bro. My mate with me in my software company was stuck in that you helped me with that and solved our problem.